# Calculating polar form of a homogenous polynomial

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the formula given on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form) for polarizing a homogenous polynomial $f(u)$ of $n$ variables $u=(u_1,u_2..,u_n)$

$$F(u^{(1)}, ...,u^{(d)}) = \frac{1}{d!} \left[\partial_{\lambda_1 }  \partial_{\lambda_2} .... \partial_{\lambda_d}   f(\sum_i \lambda_i u^{(i)}) \right]|_{\lambda=0} \tag{1}$$

I tried to run with it for the example  $f(x,y)=x^3 + 2xy^2$ with what I understood:

Set $(x,y) = \lambda_1 (x_1, y_1) + \lambda_2(x_2,y_2)+\lambda_3(x_3,y_3)$.

So, $f(x,y)= f(\lambda_1(x_1,y_1) + \lambda_2 (x_2,y_2) + \lambda_3 (x_3,y_3) )$. Now, I can't figure out how to exactly calculate:

$$ \partial_{\lambda_1} \partial_{\lambda_2} \partial_{\lambda_3}f(\lambda_1(x_1,y_1) + \lambda_2 (x_2,y_2) + \lambda_3 (x_3,y_3) )$$

Chain rule tells me that, $\partial_{\lambda_i}  f(\lambda_1(x_1,y_1) + \lambda_2 (x_2,y_2) + \lambda_3 (x_3,y_3)) =  (x_i,y_i) \cdot  \nabla f$ .. but I'm not sure how to show this or if there is a better way

Btw I'm taking that $\lambda=0$ means that $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2..,\lambda_d)=0$

Comment: Not an answer. I have never done this by actually differentiating. Clearly one just has to be able to deal with monomials. If I were doing say $x^3 y^2 z$ I'd take the appropriate multiple of the sum of all $x_{i_1}x_{i_2}x_{i_3}y_{i_4}y_{i_5}z_{i_6}$ with distinct $i_r$.

Comment: I think it might be easier to start with the explanation on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_curve